# How to wrap a list around an image and indent the list items at the same time?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CEWsT/) demonstrating the problem. What happens is that I cannot see the indented list normally if it's wrapped-around an image (which is floated left). I tried adding `margin-left: [some value];` but only the list below the image shows the margin (as in visibly). I know the upper list also receives margin but since it's wrapping around, the image sort of serves as its left margin already.

Is there a way around this?